# Autosearch is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, search, autocomplete

default magento search work using hit enter key or submit button.but now i need this search work only for pressing submit button and not work for hit enter key.For this am added the below js code in form.mini.phtml file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#search_mini_form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but this code is not working when there is the code for autocomplete

```
//<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
```

By removing this autocomplete code the above code works correctly.But i need both codes work correctly(i need autocomplete property also).I am using magento 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked it on my local machine and its working with both the code.
Please use below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '');
    searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#search_mini_form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

It disables the enter key press and also keeps default autocomplete functionality working.
**UPDATES**
I have checked the issue and found below.
the function `initAutocomplete` is defined in `js/varien/js.js` file. which is like below.

```
initAutocomplete : function(url, destinationElement){
    new Ajax.Autocompleter(
        this.field,
        destinationElement,
        url,
        {
            paramName: this.field.name,
            method: 'get',
            minChars: 2,
            updateElement: this._selectAutocompleteItem.bind(this),
            onShow : function(element, update) {
                if(!update.style.position || update.style.position=='absolute') {
                    update.style.position = 'absolute';
                    Position.clone(element, update, {
                        setHeight: false,
                        offsetTop: element.offsetHeight
                    });
                }
                Effect.Appear(update,{duration:0});
            }

        }
    );
}
```

This function makes a call to `_selectAutocompleteItem` function which is also defined in the same file,

```
_selectAutocompleteItem : function(element){
    if(element.title){
        this.field.value = element.title;
    }
    this.form.submit();
}
```

Here, you can find code `this.form.submit();` which is responsible for form submission. If you comment out the code like,

```
_selectAutocompleteItem : function(element){
    if(element.title){
        this.field.value = element.title;
    }
    //this.form.submit();
}
```

It will work as per your requirements. I can't find a way to override the `_selectAutocompleteItem` function.

Comment: this code is not working for me

Comment: Please try with updated code.

Comment: sorry the updated code is not working

Comment: What issue you are facing? I have checked it with Magento 1.8.0 and its working. Is there any JS error in your browser console?

Comment: plz check in magento 1.9.2.0. console shows   ReferenceError: myKeyPress is not defined

Comment: It seems like there is some other javascript conflicting with your code because there is no code in my answer which includes `myKeyPress` Are you using any custom module for search auto complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54556/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-venu-gopal).